# shell script giving error

Tags: shell-script

I have a small shell script which is throwing error:

> unexpected end of file

The script follows:

```
#!
if [  t -eq  1  ]
then
 echo " TEST1 "
else
echo " TEST LAST LOOP "
fi
```

Comment: What's the output of `sed -n l < your-script`?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the script that should give that error.  If you run the script with `sh ./script.sh`, it will produce

```
 TEST LAST LOOP
```

as output.  If running it with `bash ./script.sh` you will get the same output, but with an additional "integer expression expected" error since `t` is not an integer (this may also happen if you run with `sh` if your `sh` is implemented by `bash`). If you run it with `./script.sh`, the shell will most likely complain with "No such file or directory" since you have not added a proper `#!`-line.

In this script, you may use `#!/bin/sh` as the `#!`-line as you only use standard POSIX features.

The test `[ t -eq 1 ]` will never be true as `t` (the character) is not an integer.  If you're setting the *variable* `t` to an integer somewhere, use `[ "$t" -eq 1 ]` in the test.

---

The only way I can get a shell to say "unexpected end of file" is by converting the script to a DOS text file and running it with `bash`.

If you get this error, then the script file is probably a DOS text file (possibly due to being created on a Windows machine).  You should run `dos2unix` on the script.

See [questions related to `dos2unix`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=dos2unix).

Comment: `[ t -eq 1]` may be true with some `sh` implementations if a `t` environment variable has been defined with a value that is an arithmetic expression that resolves to `1`. For instance, `t=20/20 ksh93 -c '[ t -eq 1 ]'` is true. `t='a[$(")]' ksh93 -c '[ t -eq 1 ]'` would give you a _'end of file' unexpected_ error.

Comment: Having said that, I agree the DOS text file format is a much more likely explanation

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nicely done with that `ksh93` thing, but the wording of the error message won't be exactly the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the shebang line `#!/bin/sh` and `t` isn't defined

Comment: None of those things would provoke an "unexpected end of file" error.

Answer (score 0):

- replace `#!` by `#!/bin/sh` or run `sh ./script.sh`, and you must set t as integer `$t` not `t`.

Comment: The answer is spot on, but it could use with a bit of expansion on the reasons for it